# Expressjs + Joi to display a custom error messages

Tags: express, joi

Need custom error message instead use default from Joi.

```
const schema = {
    email: Joi.string().email().label("Email Address"),
    password: Joi.string()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer, but I still need multiple language for custom message.

```
const schema = {
    email: Joi.string().email().label("Email Address").error(err => {
      err.forEach(error => {
        switch(error.type){
          case "string.base":
            error.message = "must be a string";
            break;
          case "string.email":
            error.message = "must be an email";
            break;
        }
      });
      return err;
    }),
    password: Joi.string()
  }
```